# Bad response from server after tinymce image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upload images using paperclip and [tinymce-rails-image-upload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload)   following [this](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload-demo) demo. I'm uploading images in a question model (that belongs to comments). When I upload, I get a 'got a bad response from the server' message and the image isn't shown in the editor, however it does create a new question.

Here is my the log after upload:

```
Processing by TinymceAssetsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"auth token", "hint"=>"", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001025a2780   @tempfile=#   <File:/var/folders/t4/86vsrmds42j84r36kwpng7k00000gn/T/RackMultipart20150207-  12522-9rj6xq>, @original_filename="applecash.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";   filename=\"applecash.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "alt"=>""}
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/t4/86vsrmds42j84r36kwpng7k00000gn/T/RackMultipart20150207-12522-9rj6xq[0]' 2>/dev/null
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
Question Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE (questions.position IS NOT NULL) AND (1 = 1) ORDER BY questions.position DESC    LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `file_content_type`
SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "questions" ("created_at", "file_content_type", "file_file_name", "file_file_size", "file_updated_at", "position", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 08 Feb 2015 18:35:07 UTC +00:00], ["file_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["file_file_name", "timcook.jpg"], ["file_file_size", 120040], ["file_updated_at", Sun, 08 Feb 2015 18:35:07 UTC +00:00], ["position", 9], ["updated_at", Sun, 08 Feb 2015 18:35:07 UTC +00:00]]
(7.3ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 8.7ms)
```

Here is the tinymce controller:

```
class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json

def create
  geometry = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file params[:file]
  question = Question.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint)

 render json: {
   question: {
   url:    question.file.url,
   height: geometry.height.to_i,
   width:  geometry.width.to_i
  }
 }, layout: false, content_type: "text/html"

 end
end
```

The questions controller create action looks like this (do I add @comment and the additional parameters to the tinymce controller?):

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
  @question = @comment.questions.new(question_params)
end
...
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:body, :comment_id, :user_id, :file, :position)
end
```

The question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file
end
```

and the editor view:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@comment, Question.new] do |f| %>    
<%= f.text_area :body, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 60 %>
<% end %>
<%= tinymce plugins: ["uploadimage"] %>
```

I'm confused as to why its creating a new question for every uploaded image and what's still causing the 'bad response' error.

Comment: you are not getting a error that looks like ***BAD ADDRESS*** or `!! #<Excon::Errors::SocketError: Bad address>`

Comment: No, no bad address error that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems tinymce-rails-imageupload expects "image" in response to uploaded file

```
render json: {
   image: {
   url:    question.file.url,
   height: geometry.height.to_i,
   width:  geometry.width.to_i
  }
 }, layout: false, content_type: "text/html"
```

Comment: line 144 and 177 in [source](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/plugin.js#L144)